# Is VBScript fulfills XPath completely?

Tags: xml, xpath, vbscript

I'm new to VBScript in dealing with XML files. I noticed that there are some vbscript commands to select certain nodes like `.ChildNodes`, `.documentElement`, `.lastChild` and stuff like that.

However, I can reach to any node using XPath along with `selectNodes`, or `selectSingleNode`. **So is the XPath not fully compatible with vbscript and so I have to use some vbscript commands to reach specific node/nodes?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In **older versions** of xml objects, you need to **specify** the selecetion langauge as XPath as in `xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"`
- Starting from **MSXML4**, XPath is the **default** selection language.
- In **MSXML2**, which is common among people working with **UFT**, it follows the XPath language *"with minor exceptions"*.

That's almost from [When does XPath property have to be set to XML DOM object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462566/when-does-xpath-property-have-to-be-set-to-xml-dom-object)

Comment: Thanks for the answer